# Python ASCII Character Count

Tags: python, ascii

I have to write a program in Python that prompts a user to enter a text and then compares this text to an ASCII string (of all the ASCII characters) with a nested loop.

```
ascii_string= """!"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"""

user_text=input("Enter a text to analyze: ")

for character in (user_text):
    total_count= len(user_text)
    for user_text in (ascii_string):
        ascii_count=len(user_text)

print("Total number of characters: ", total_count)
print("Total number of ASCII characters: ", ascii_count)
print("Total number of non-ASCII characters: ", total_count-ascii_count)
```

Comment: can you give a sample input and a sample output please?

Comment: Here is a sample running of the program.

    Enter a text to analyze: Let’s go the café!

    Total number of characters: 18
    Total number of ASCII characters: 16
    Total number of non-ASCII characters: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are indeed using an unsuitable algorithm. For each character in input the string, you're saving the length of the whole input string, then looking at each character in the ASCII string and saving the length of the whole input string. Again.

Instead, add up all the boolean values of "is in the ASCII string" by passing a generator to `sum()`, which will add up all these boolean values (`True` is `1` and `False` is `0`):

```
ascii_string = set("""!"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~""")

user_text = input("Enter a text to analyze: ")

total_count = len(user_text)
ascii_count = sum(c in ascii_string for c in user_text)

print("Total number of characters:", total_count)
print("Total number of ASCII characters:", ascii_count)
print("Total number of non-ASCII characters:", total_count-ascii_count)
```

Comment: I'd cast `ascii_string` to a `set` as well since we are only ever testing for membership.

Comment: Well, it's all unique characters anyway, so all we gain is a faster lookup (I think? not sure) at the cost of creating a hash table. I guess the performance increase, if any, depends on the size of the user input string.

Comment: Looks like it is indeed faster. If we need to do thousands or millions of membership tests, `ascii_string=set(ascii_string)` would be a good optimization.

Comment: @dursk - Changed it to a `set` for you.

Answer (score 3):

A better, simpler and faster way:

```py
>>> s = "asdmlfjkéàç&-è'("
>>> ascii_count = len(s.encode("ascii", "ignore"))
>>> ascii_count
12
```